# Altering userres and delband tables after set_resource_limit(-1, -1, -1)

Tags: ram, table, cpu, resources, net

For a private network to remove ram net cpu i set the resource limit to unlimited for each newaccount created. By chaging [set_resource_limits](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.contracts/blob/f6578c45c83ec60826e6a1eeb9ee71de85abe976/contracts/eosio.system/src/eosio.system.cpp#L358) to `set_resource_limits( newact, -1, -1, -1 );` //unlimited resources

Is it possible to and should I alter the userres and delegatebw tables ? maybe set the net/cpu weight to -1 or unlimited if possible to do so

Do the values in userres table matter after we set_resource_limit to unlimited?

What other changes should be made to make accounts completely free from ram net and cpu?

P.S
*I am aware this approach of removing ram CPU and net is not sound at all.*

Image showing unlimited account throwing CPU limit error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userres` table does nothing about resource (CPU/NET) allocation and consumption. It depends on `set_resource_limits` only, and `userres` or `delband` manage staked or delegated amount of EOS and make it available to utilize this information from `eosio` and other accounts' contract.

Comment: After changing to `set_resource_limits( newact, -1, -1, -1 )`
I used this command to create a newaccount
`cleos system newaccount tester3 --transfer tester.11 PB_KEY --stake-net "0.0001 ILO" --stake-cpu "0.0001 ILO" --buy-ram-kbytes 8 -p tester3@active`
It was created successfully but when I tried to push some action with tester.11 
I got `Error 3080004:Transaction exceeded the current CPU usage limit imposed on the transaction
Error Details:
billed CPU time (586 us) is greater than the maximum billable CPU time for the transaction (21 us)`
How could this happen with unlimited resources

Comment: Check `cleos get account tester.11`. Is CPU and NET set unlimited?

Comment: YesI I have edited the question and added an image there showing unlimited account throwing _exceeding cpu limit_   error.

Comment: CPU and NET bandwidth are measured in the finalization step of transaction execution. If you send delegatebw for unlimited account itself, set_resource_limits() will be called with positive values (staked amount here) and unlimited resources are cancelled.